# Access: Query Split text for each recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table in access called "RZ6", where I have a field called [GRID REF].
The values of [GRID REF] look like this:
"575583 / 151011"

Now I want to use "/" as a delimiter and separate "575583" and "151011" into separate fields, ideally called "X" and "Y" respectively.

I have 168 records like the above, that need to split out. All in the same [GRID REF] field. Can this be done automatically ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Left](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_left.asp), [Mid](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_mid.asp) and [Instr](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_instr.asp) functions. And also [aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

Comment: @VincentG Yes, for now i have used Left and Right. Since each part had remained as 6 characters. Problem is, this data is from an excel sheet that will be updated. Therefore I wanted to use a function like text to columns (in excel), as they may not always be 6 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a pain, but you could add a VBA function, then call it from your query.

```
Public Function Splitter(strFieldValue As String, intElement As Integer) As Variant
    Dim varTmp  As Variant

    varTmp = Split(Replace(strFieldValue, " ", ""), "/")
    If UBound(varTmp) = 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve varTmp(UBound(varTmp) + 1)
    End If

    Splitter = varTmp(intElement)
End Function
```

So, remove any spaces up front, then attempt to split on a forward slash.  I added a basic check for two elements being returned, but you can continue this further to harden the logic.

Within your query, you'd then make two calls to get the first and second parts of the text:

```
SELECT [GRID REF]
    , Splitter([GRID REF], 0) AS Easting
    , Splitter([GRID REF], 1) AS Northing
FROM RZ6;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a work around, in sql, following Vincent G comments.

```
SELECT [GRID REF], trim(left([GRID REF],(instr([GRID REF],"/")-1))) as Easting , 
trim(Right(Trim([GRID REF]),(len([GRID REF]) - instr([GRID REF],"/")))) as Northing 
from RZ6 ;
```

If anyone has another way of doing this, then please let me know.

Comment: Using `Mid` is easier that using `Right` (no need to get the `Len` of the string). One `Trim` is enough if you do it last.